# Стек из char и int

Tags: типы-данных, алгоритм, стек, преобразование

Доброго времени суток! Реализую потихоньку опз, операции +,-,*, со скобками, отрицательными и многозначными числами. Много всего, а потому назрела идея в ходе начального считывания выражения сразу вычислять число и в стек закидывать его, а не символ (например, 343+25, чтобы в стек шло 343,25,+ ). Но стек char-овый, тк храню еще знаки, скобки. Была идея привести многозначное число к типу char, а потом обратно, но в Unicode лишь до 511, так поняла, нумерация числовая идет.

Comment: Эээ... а какая ваша основная задача? Вы пишете парсер арифметических выражений?

(И что, простите, в Unicode до 511?)

Answer (score 4):

Обычно когда пишут подобные парсеры, делают структуру вида

```
typedef enum {
    OPERATION,
    OPERAND,
    BRACE,
    ... // другие типы токенов, которые поддерживает ваш парсер
} token_type;

typedef struct {
    token_type type;
    union {
        char c;
        int i;
        ... // другие типы данных, которые может принимать токен
    } value;
} token;
```

В стеке храниет не `char`'ы, а `token`'ы. Когда выделяете токен, записываете его в эту структуру и проставляете нужный `token_type`. Затем по нему можно будет определить, какого типа токен вы вытащили и производить соответствующие его типу действия.